# IBM Worklight 5.0.6.1 - Android 2.3 Support

Tags: cordova, ibm-mobilefirst

When I run the Worklight application on Android Virtual Devices - Android 2.3.3 (API Level 10). The following error appears when the app is launched. It is fine when running on Android 2.2 (API Level 8).

I have searched on Internet and here said that there is bug on Android 2.3 about webview. [(Link)](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=12987)

May I know does Worklight 5.0.6.1 supports Android 2.3?

```
11-25 15:51:50.001: WARN/dalvikvm(615): JNI WARNING: jarray 0xb746d460 points to non-array object (Ljava/lang/String;)
11-25 15:51:50.001: INFO/dalvikvm(615): "WebViewCoreThread" prio=5 tid=8 NATIVE
11-25 15:51:50.001: INFO/dalvikvm(615):   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0xb7477290 self=0x98e7da9
11-25 15:51:50.001: INFO/dalvikvm(615):   | sysTid=1348 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=[fopen-error:2] handle=160581160
11-25 15:51:50.011: INFO/dalvikvm(615):   at android.webkit.JWebCoreJavaBridge.sharedTimerFired(Native Method)
11-25 15:51:50.011: INFO/dalvikvm(615):   at android.webkit.JWebCoreJavaBridge.sharedTimerFired(Native Method)
11-25 15:51:50.020: INFO/dalvikvm(615):   at android.webkit.JWebCoreJavaBridge.fireSharedTimer(JWebCoreJavaBridge.java:91)
11-25 15:51:50.020: INFO/dalvikvm(615):   at android.webkit.JWebCoreJavaBridge.handleMessage(JWebCoreJavaBridge.java:108)
11-25 15:51:50.020: INFO/dalvikvm(615):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-25 15:51:50.020: INFO/dalvikvm(615):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
11-25 15:51:50.020: INFO/dalvikvm(615):   at android.webkit.WebViewCore$WebCoreThread.run(WebViewCore.java:629)
11-25 15:51:50.020: INFO/dalvikvm(615):   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
11-25 15:51:50.030: ERROR/dalvikvm(615): VM aborting
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Worklight does support Android 2.3, see [System Requirements](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27024838). However, there is a defect open to document the Android emulator issue you pointed out. The Known Limitations section of the InfoCenter will be updated to indicate Android Emulator 2.3.x is not supported.

Comment: This is correct. It's a known Android 2.3.x emulator issue, it crashes when running Cordova based apps.